# Does Cognito Forms support white Labeling?

Tags: cognito-forms

We would like to use one of our subdomains to present a form but want everything hosted by Cognito Forms. The idea is to make it look like they are still on one of our sites even though they are not, so we can allow a non-programmer to create and distribute forms.

Is this possible? How can this be done?

Comment: Please note that this site is not affiliated with Cognito Forms. While the Cognito develop team is active here answering implementation questions, support requests should be directed to them directly at their site. Please take the [tour] to learn more about _this_ site.

Comment: Their site directed me to ask this question here. Thanks

Comment: I'm dubious. Even so, your question needs to not be phrased as a direct support request. I've taken a stab at re-phrasing.

Comment: Thanks, added more clarification for what functionality I was looking to add as well.

Comment: I will reopen this, but I agree with @AlE.that this should be directed at their customer service rather than toward our audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a PRO user at Cognito Forms. And I also wanted this feature.

White labeling is possible for the *Forms*.
In fact they have a special embed feature that puts the forms 'inline',
not an iframe, so it really is a nice solution.
(*it also has iframe if you want that)

*However*
Notifications via email currently show `notifications@cognitoforms.com` so not exactly white label when you get a notification sent to your customer.

*If* you don't plan on sending your customer anything (like an email confirmation of any sort) then *yes* it acts like white-label very well.

*But*, if you reply to your customer via *their* email response system (Mandrill) they are required *currently* to add `notifications@cognitoforms.com` in the display name, making it obvious that you are using Cognito Forms.

Answer (score 2):

Using the embed code from the Publish page in your builder, you can easily [embed your form onto your website](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/10/style--publish) to create a more custom experience for your users. The form will still update automatically with any changes made in the builder, so there is no coding involved for the non-programmers who are building the forms.

All forms are hosted on Cognito Forms' servers, whether they are embedded or accessed through the public link.

Comment: I appreciate your response, having done more research I have determined what I am looking for is called white labeling. We don't want to have to add it to one our web pages since that would require a programmer to go in for each new form created. How ever it doesn't seem like this is possible with Cognito so I will make your answer as correct unless I hear otherwise.